# The value of variable shown on the Watch in the debug mode of visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, watch

[image]

[image]

As you can see, when the execution is at line 11, the variables a, b, c and d do not exist, but as soon as the execution is at line 12, all those variables are set to their default values (according to what are shown on the Watch 1).

Hence, may I conclude that as soon as the execution goes into a scope, all the variables that is visible with respect to that scope will be set to their default values even before the execution reaches the declarations?

If so, I am confused because if we put `Console.WriteLine(a);` just after line 12, it will give an error as the variable a has not been declared at that point.

So may I ask **why the watch shows that variables a, b, c and d already have (default) values at line 12?** More specifically, if the variables a, b, c and d do not exist and are not set to 0, false, 0 and null respectively at line 12, why is the watch showing those information?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you care? We can try and explain what you are seeing to you, but the explanation won't be of any use to you at all since _in practice_ the value is only accessible after it is set.

Comment: @mjwills Hi, thank you very much for your reply :) I'm new to the debugging features in visual studio so I would like to understand the way it works as much as possible. If you think the answer to this question is not practical, could you please just very briefly explain what is happening there? Greatly appreciated

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for your advice. I think it will just help me feel more consistent on how I understand the programming language works and how the IDE works. But if you think this answer is pointless... then I assume it is pointless after all

Comment: @J-A-S, According to my test, I found that the fact is that when we access the opening brace, the compiler will automatically initialize the variables in the braces (not including the nested braces), so your situation is normal.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Thank you for your attention :) This may not be relevant to this question but if you are using visual studio 2022 (preview), did you notice that it is being extreme slow when you run a project for the first a few times? I'm pretty sure my hardware is good enough, or maybe it is because I've installed too many workloads?

Comment: @J-A-S, about your question related to Visual studio 2022, I recommend that you could report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).